# Does the http request automatically retry?

Tags: http, go

I am trying to push my data to apache server using GoLang. Suppose my apache server is temporarily stopped. Then will my http request retry automatically.
I am using this statement

```
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "http request error")
    }
```

I am unable to proceed further coz what is think is my execution is stuck here. And I am repeatedly getting this error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you will need to implement your own retry method, this is a basic example that could give you an idea:

https://play.golang.org/p/_o5AgePDEXq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var (
        err      error
        response *http.Response
        retries  int = 3
    )
    for retries > 0 {
        response, err = http.Get("https://non-existent")
        // response, err = http.Get("https://google.com/robots.txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            retries -= 1
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    if response != nil {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("data = %s\n", data)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to mock or test for unit testing this?

Comment: @RAVIBANGKITNURZIKRILLAH you can use the [httptest](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest) package

Comment: wouldn't this be better implemented in a custom transport?

Answer (score 15):

You can use more cleaner implementation of retrying by using retryablehttp
https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp which handles most of the conditions

This is provides customisation for retry policy, backoffs etc.

Comment: What if I want to give some timeout to a request, like we do in Default http.Client
tr := &http.Transport{
IdleConnTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
Here we can give IdleConnTimeout, can we do the same with go-retryablehttp?

Comment: @yashjain12yj: You can set Timeout on Client.HTTPClient.Timeout 
Can checkout https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp#Client formore reference

Comment: That library, unfortunately, does not handle the case of client timeouts, see: https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/issues/167

Comment: I can confirm that the current implementation (at the time of writing) doesn't handle (retry) on client timed out.