# Golang http automatically retrying on StatusRequestTimeout (408) response

Tags: timeout, chromium

> Setup

I have two different applications, both written in Go. The first is the server, and second is a smaller app that makes calls to the server. They use the `http` package for making calls and the `router` package for setting up endpoints.

> The Problem

When the device makes a specific call to the server a 408 (StatusRequestTimeout) response is returned. This response is not due to our server actually timing out, but just used to describe the error (more info on this below). The first time the device makes this call it receives the 408 and proceeds normally. However, if the same call is made again a new 'third' call being sent to the server immediately after the second call has finished. This third call is the same as the first two. There is no http retry logic enabled for this call.

> The bug

Why is this third call being issued? When the code is updated to instead return a 400 status response instead of a 408 this third call is no longer made. Additionally changing different calls to return a 408 instead of a 400 will start to exhibit the same behavior of sending a triplicate third call. I have been unable to find documentation to explain this behavior, or other articles which describe it.

> Hunch

I have found many articles like [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3257-google-chrome-will-automatically-retry-requests-on-certain-error-responses.htm) one which indicate browsers will sometimes retry requests. Additionally some other stackoverflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676817/does-the-http-request-automatically-retry) indicate that the http request doesn't retry without setting up our own retry logic. Again, we have set this up, but it is not enabled for this given call, and debugging shows that we do not ever enter our custom retry logic.

I believe that this is a chromium feature. I've tried to replicate this with firefox, but I haven't been successful, however Edge exhibits the same behavior. Chromes dev tools (and edge) however only show two network calls, the first and the third. I think it could also be the http library, but it is very strange that the behavior is different between browsers.

> Bug Fix

Given the nature of what a 408 response is supposed to entail I have decided to move away from using them for custom error responses. At this point, I'm just more curious about why the behavior is as it is, if my hunch is correct, or if there is something else at play.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start from method `is408Message()` which is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L2256). It checks that the buffer carries `408 Request timeout` status code. This method is used by another [method](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L2238) to inspect the response from server and in case of `408 Request Timeout` the `persistConn` is closed with an `errServerClosedIdle` error. The error is [assigned](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L2702) to `persistConn.closed` field.

In the [main loop](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L561) of http `Transport`, there is a call to `persistConn.roundTrip` [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L594) which as an error returns the value stored in `persistConn.closed` field. Few lines [below](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L606) you can find a method called `pconn.shouldRetryRequest` which takes as an argument the error returned by `persistConn.roundTrip` and returns true when the error is `errServerClosedIdle`. Since the whole operation is wrapped by the for loop the request will be sent again.

It could be valuable for you to analyze [`shouldRetryRequest` method](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/052da5717e02659da49707873b3868fe36f2aaf0/src/net/http/transport.go#L681) because there are multiple conditions which must be met to retry the request. For example the request will not be repeated when the connection was used for the first time.